# Selecting the minimum point in a polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute

I am attempting to find the minimum point value within a polygon using ArcGIS 10.3. I have two datasets: 1) A series of polygons & 2) A series of points scattered about. After selecting a given polygon, I can use Select by Location where the polygon selects the points within it. From this, I would like to select the minimum value point within the selection. However, after running this `[numeric column] =  (SELECT MIN([numeric column]) FROM [table])` code I get no results since the minimum value in the entirety of the numeric column is not contained within my selection. I do not know how to reference my current selection. I have tried the Select from Current Selection option, but that did not help.

Comment: I dont really follow some of your question.  So you have joined your points to the polygons and you have given the polygon.  Would it not be possible on the join of points to poly to select the summarize minimum attributes. That should give the polygon the smallest value for the point that it contains.  Am I following your question correctly?  Do you have some screenshots of the tables you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your features selected, you have two options:

- Run Summary Statistics on the "numeric column" which will return the min, max, average, and other statistical measures on said column. If you're manually iterating through the subsets of points, this is easy: open the attribute table, right click on the column heading and select "Statistics".
- If you need to handle this in a programmatic fashion, you'll likely need to employ Python or ModelBuilder to perform the selection steps for each polygon, and then save the statistics (keeping only the minimum) out to a new table.

Comment: thanks! You got it. I implemented a modification of the two methods you suggested. First, tried summary statistics as a tool and then added that into a model. I'll work on converting it to Python shortly.